# Mosquitto ACL can't define user-specific specification unless all users are specified

Tags: acl, mosquitto

Can anyone see what's wrong with this ACL?  It is the most simple of configurations, but doesn't work.

My goal is to have:

1. all regular users read and write to [username]/#.
2. all regular users can also read from the admin at sys/$
3. a user named 'system' can read/write to all routes, and importantly, to sys/#

The following configuration, as far as I can tell, should work, but doesn't:

```
pattern %u/#        
topic read sys/#    

user system         
topic #
```

Whenever I specify a configuration for any one user ('system' in this case), all other users can no longer connect.

If I comment out the 'topic #' under that specific user, it works, but of course then my 'system' user can no longer send to sys/#.

```
pattern %u/#        
topic read sys/#    

user system         
#topic #
```

It works if I provide specifications for each of the users individually, such as the following:

```
topic read sys/#
pattern %u/#

user system
topic #

#-- begin user-specific specifications

user george
topic george/#

user kathy
topic katy/#        

user moe
topic katy/#   [... etc]
```

I can grow the ACL file programmatically, but it seems I should have to, and the first ACL should work.
Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

PS.. here is my config file:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
listener 1883 localhost
listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.<domain>.com/fullchain.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.<domain>.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.<domain>.com/privkey.pem
require_certificate false
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/acl
log_type none
log_dest topic
log_dest stdout
connection_messages false
```

Comment: Do you have a matching password file? Also do you have `allow_anonymous true` in the mosquitto.conf? What version of Mosquitto are you using?

Comment: I am using passwords in all cases.  I just added my config to the original message.  I'm using TLS, no client certificates, but I am requiring passwords.  The accounts all log in with no problem using passwords other than stated above.  Mosquitto version: 1.4.8

Comment: The `topic read sys/#` shouldn't do anything since you have `allow_anonymous false` and they only apply to anonymous users